# Command Bound to Keyboard Input not Firing

Tags: wpf, command, keyboard-shortcuts, community-toolkit-mvvm, inputbinding

I'm using the MVVM Community toolkit (v 8.2) in a learning project that implements the Risk board game.

I have a working command for some custom buttons, so I know the basics are functioning. But when I add commands bound to Keyboard input, they never fire (breakpoints are never reached), and I can't tell why.

I worried about Focus for a while, but the problem persists even when Window.Focusable=True explicitly, or when the InputBindings are on child elements like a background image or custom buttons (mentioned previously).

I've found many helpful answers to closely related questions here and elsewhere online, but nothing has resolved my specific issue.

MainWindow View XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RiskMVVM2.MainWindow"
        ...
        Width="1820" Height="1062" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" Name="GameWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None"
        FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="12" >

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding ConfirmInputCommand}" />
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Shift+Return" Command="{Binding SkipPlayerTurnCommand}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

MainWindow Constructor (View code-behind):

```
public MainWindow(RiskBoardVM VM, List<Brush> playerColors)
{
     this.DataContext = VM;

     ...

     InitializeComponent();

     ...
}
```

Relevant ViewModel Code:

```
...
     private bool CanConfirmInput()
     {
          return true;
     }

     [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanConfirmInput))]
     private void ConfirmInput()
     {
         CurrentGame.State.IncrementPhase();
     }

     private bool CanSkipPlayerTurn()
     {
         if ((int)CurrentPhase > (int)GamePhase.Place) return true;
         else return false;
     }


     [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSkipPlayerTurn))]
     private void SkipPlayerTurn()
     {
         CurrentGame.State.IncrementPlayerTurn();
     }
...
```

Comment: I have no problem with that InputBinding. Works as expected

Comment: Just because the element you want to receive the command has `Focusable` set to true does not mean it is going to receive the keystroke.  Whatever element has keyboard focus will.   If that element eats the keystroke and marks the event as handled, you are out of luck.   Do yourself a favor:  at app startup time put in some temporary code to call `Keyboard.AddGotFocusHandler` and `Keyboard.AddLostKeyboardFocusHandler`.  In the event handlers, dump out to the debug window (or log window) what the type of the element is.  It is very useful in debugging this